# Testing a class based Django view which returns a JsonReponse

Tags: python, json, django, testing

What is the proper way to test a class based Django view which returns a JsonResponse type. For example, the beginning of my class looks like this:

```
class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request):

        return JsonResponse({
            "status": 200,
            "message": "message to return."
        })
```

I have similar 'post' and 'delete' functions. The url `/myview` is connected to this view. When I attempt something like this:

```
c = Client()
response = c.get('/myview')
```

'response' is a HttpResponsePermanentRedirect type, and I am unsure how the JSON data can be obtained from that.

EDIT --
I login in the setup of the test

Comment: Does the redirect go to `/myview/`?

Comment: also you have LoginRequiredMixin which means you should login your client prior to request
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

Comment: yes, executing response['location'] gives /myview/ .

Comment: Also I do login, it is just not shown here

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#append-slash, in other words always use routes with trailing slash

Comment: Then `/myview/` is the URL you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add the trailing slash to your URL

```
c.get('/myview/')
```

if `APPEND_SLASH` is turned on (and I think Django turns it on by default), any request **without** the trailing slash will generate a redirect to a URL **with** the trailing slash